# CarrierWave: resize default images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I've been using CarrierWave to successfully resize my images and I've recently added a default image (`default_url`) to some of my uploaders. However, it doesn't seem to resize my default images.

Is there a way to force to resizing of these images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not on a file level -- Carrierwave doesn't actually manage or touch these default_urls. You'll need to get that file in the proper size.

Or, you can reduce the size via CSS if it is in the same dimension.

But generally, you'll need to just get the default images in their proper size.